# QGIS mbtiles vs xyz tiles export inconsistency

Tags: qgis, mbtiles

I want to use mbtiles in a project so I am generating mbtiles for a selected area of osm.

Extent (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):

```
463297.84985694464,538040.0735187809,6769150.388750425,6834675.317430764 [EPSG:3857]
```

I was a bit surprised to find out that I wasn't able to find a record for these values

```
z = 14
y = 5412
x = 8390
```

Query I am running:

```sql
select tile_data from tiles where zoom_level=14 and tile_column=8390 and tile_row=5412;
```

has no results.

However

```sql
select tile_data from tiles where zoom_level=14 and tile_column=8390;
```

has 28 results, where tile_row ranges from 10960 through 10987.

So I thought I would take xyz tile exports for the same area and settings to see if it has a tile for the given xyz and IT DOES!

I don't understand how this is possible! Is there something I am missing while exporting mbtiles? OR is this a bug in QGIS?

Comment: Ah! I think this might be the issue here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33228

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of QGIS mbtiles export is to use TMS scheme instead of xyz scheme. Hence the discrepancy. I read this nice post about [xyz and tms](https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4954720) which helped me in doing the conversion. Simply converting the y value to `pow(2, z) - y - 1` does the job. Here's the [QGIS issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33228#issuecomment-577618737) for anyone interested in following through.